# How to show a changing number on the statusbar?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-drawable

I am creating an Android app in which I need to display a number in system tray which keeps changing.
I want something like the screenshot below:

[image]

The network speed, shown in the screenshot keeps changing. I have tried using `setSmallIcon` but it only accepts Drawable resources.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376300/how-do-i-show-text-in-android-system-status-bar

Comment: @GeorgePJ this isn't the solution