# How can I display numbers in status bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-drawable, statusbar

[image]I am working on an application where I need to show the download speed in status bar. I have tried using `notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon()` but it takes a constant drawable as parameter. I want the number to change after every 3 seconds. I have seen many apps that show some number in status bar e.g temperature, download percentage etc. So, there is a way for sure. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: Check this guide https://medium.com/@britt.barak/notifications-part-2-progress-indicator-2aa4cdea24c6

Comment: @Ikazuchi thats not what I want.. I want varying number to display as notification icon. I have added a screenshot in my question for further demonstration

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376300/how-do-i-show-text-in-android-system-status-bar

Comment: if it works please notify me

Comment: @AMALKG i have already tried all these solutions. They are kind of outdated i guess. Nothing worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by converting text string to bitmap drawable.

Use below method to convert your text to bitmap. And use return bitmap as smallIcon in notification builder.

```
public Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float textSize, int textColor) {
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setColor(textColor);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    float baseline = -paint.ascent(); // ascent() is negative
    int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.5f); // round
    int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 0.5f);
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, baseline, paint);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: setSmallIcon doesn't accept `Bitmap` or `Icon`. notificationbuilder which had setSmallIcon(icon) is deprecated now