# How to set number instead of icon to status bar on android

Tags: java, android, icons, statusbar

I want to make a timer/reminder that will show number of minutes until ring starts at status bar. 
It needs to be updated every minute automatically, and I know how to set icon but I don't know how to set number to be there instead of icon, so I don't want to have 30 icons of numbers... instead is there any option to somehow convert numbers to icons and show it on status bar every minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **status bar** means notification bar, according to [this document](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification), there is no way to put a text or number into the icon place. You may show the remaining time in the title or text in the notification as a normal App doing.

Edit: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376300/how-do-i-show-text-in-android-system-status-bar) is what you want. There is a method which **converts numbers to icon** format. You may pass the converted numbers to the icon parameter.

Comment: It is status bar, top bar with little icons and battery status, time etc. It is possible because I sow in one app that it have that feature, I suppose they created icon for every number and then they changing them. It is quite useful to have that info in status bar so you don't need to close current app to see how much time you have.

Comment: @pastela 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376300/how-do-i-show-text-in-android-system-status-bar this thread is what you want. there is a method which converts number to icon.

Comment: yes, that is quite helpful, edit your answer adding that content so I can upvote it.