# How to change text in status bar dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-notifications, statusbar

I want to create an app that will `show internet speed as notification in status bar` the problem is that when i create notification it only shows icon but i think this is not the way (`if you think there is a way using this then how ?`) i used this codes snippet to show notification but what changes to do if i want the result that others are getting as you can see also in screen shot in the `leftmost side` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contenIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID_2)
            .setLargeIcon(getBitmapFromString("22", 20, this))
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Description")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(contenIntent)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setTicker("23")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.screen_background_light_transparent)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
```

[image: status bar screen shot]

The text changes in notification per second and it is not fake.
I have already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45392031/12837534) but not accurate since it overlaps with notification icon.
`Any help` will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Please is there anybody who can solve this because there is no reference to do this in stackoverflow also i have searched a lot

Comment: have you got your answer?

Comment: @ShoaibK. Nope i did not found anything, don't know how they (app like speed meter) do so..

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376300/how-do-i-show-text-in-android-system-status-bar/65155581#65155581 Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: if you need more help in showing wifi speed with the unit, I will answer that too.

Comment: Checked your answer great +1 but that way of showing smallIcon as bitmap works only for api level 23 and above but if we want it for lower api then what could be the possiblities ?

Comment: I'm also wondering that what it could be for >23.

Comment: anybody who knows the solution for this may post over here

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the text that you want to display on a bitmap and then set that as an icon to the notification.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID_2);

notification.setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(getBitmapIcon()))
```

implement `getBitmapIcon()` and return the bitmap icon that you want to display.

Comment: I have already tried this `notification.setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(getBitmapIcon()))` but setSmallIcon only says wrong argument type i.e, it requires int how to solve this problem.

Comment: And also setSmallIcon(Bitmap bitmap) is added in api level 23 but the other app like from screen shot above i am able to run the app in api level 22 also.How they do that ?

Comment: I am not sure about this but they might have used this class :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification
It is deprecated now though.

Comment: @MdAman, for api level >= 23, use the `setSmallIcon(Bitmap bitmap)` and get the `bitmap` object like explained here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45376679/9167710

Comment: @cgb_pandey .setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(bitmap)) is throwing error message says, (int) can not be applied to (android.grapjics.Bitmap)

Comment: You said earlier that there exists a method `setSmallIcon(Bitmap bitmap)` which was added in api level 23. Just now, I tried and I didn't found it. Without such method, I think it is difficult to show the text as icon in status bar.